# Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, variadic-functions

Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function, from an array?

```
var arr = ['a','b','c']

var func = function()
{
    // debug 
    alert(arguments.length);
    //
    for(arg in arguments)
        alert(arg);
}

func('a','b','c','d'); // prints 4 which is what I want, then 'a','b','c','d'
func(arr); // prints 1, then 'Array'
```

I've recently written a lot of Python and it's a wonderful pattern to be able to accept varargs and send them. e.g.

```
def func(*args):
   print len(args)
   for i in args:
       print i

func('a','b','c','d'); // prints 4 which is what I want, then 'a','b','c','d'
func(*arr) // prints 4 which is what I want, then 'a','b','c','d'
```

Is it possible in JavaScript to send an array to be treated **as** the arguments array?

Comment: Note that its not a good idea to use a `for - in` loop with the `arguments` object - a 'normal' for loop iterating over the `length` property should be used instead

Comment: it's never been a problem, can you ellaborate as to why that is the case? arguments object is almost always small enough to have a negligible performance improvement for using the agruments[0..length-1] version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Comment: I think that arguments is not an actual array, but a special object, so the "in" syntax might not work, depending on the JS implementation.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

**Update**: Since ES6, you can simply use the [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when calling the function:

```
func(...arr);
```

Since ES6 also if you expect to treat your arguments as an array, you can also use the spread syntax in the parameter list, for example:

```
function func(...args) {
  args.forEach(arg => console.log(arg))
}

const values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
func(...values)
func(1, 2, 3)
```

And you can combine it with normal parameters, for example if you want to receive the first two arguments separately and the rest as an array:

```
function func(first, second, ...theRest) {
  //...
}
```

And maybe is useful to you, that you can know how many arguments a function expects:

```
var test = function (one, two, three) {}; 
test.length == 3;
```

But anyway you can pass an arbitrary number of arguments...

The spread syntax is shorter and "sweeter" than `apply` and if you don't need to set the `this` value in the function call, this is the way to go.

Here is an [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Function:apply) example, which was the former way to do it:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];

function func() {
  console.log(this); // 'test'
  console.log(arguments.length); // 3

  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }

};

func.apply('test', arr);
```

Nowadays I only recommend using `apply` only if you need to pass an arbitrary number of arguments from an array **and** set the `this` value. `apply` takes is the `this` value as the first arguments, which will be used on the function invocation, if we use `null` in non-strict code, the `this` keyword will refer to the Global object (window) inside `func`, in strict mode, when explicitly using 'use strict' or in ES modules, `null` will be used.

Also note that the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object is not really an Array, you can convert it by:

```
var argsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

And in ES6:

```
const argsArray = [...arguments] // or Array.from(arguments)
```

But you rarely use the `arguments` object directly nowadays thanks to the spread syntax.

Comment: Thanks, apply does the trick, call in this case does not work. was that written in by mistake?

Comment: How do you do it if the function is actually a member of a class?  Is this right?   theObject.member.apply(theObject, arguments);

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` prevents browser JS optimizations like V8. [Details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: **1.** Apparently, `arguments` is planned to be deprecated in favor of [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). I don't have a source for this, but I heard it somewhere. **2.** [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that using `slice` on the `arguments` object prevents optimizations in engines like V8. They suggest using the "despised Array constructor", `Array.from(arguments)`, or `[...arguments]`. Would you care to update your answer for ES2015?

Comment: NB: I went ahead and wrote [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219199/1175714).

Answer (score 78):

You can actually pass as many values as you want to any javascript function.  The explicitly named parameters will get the first few values, but ALL parameters will be stored in the arguments array.

To pass the arguments array in "unpacked" form, you can use apply, like so (c.f. [Functional Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript)):

```
var otherFunc = function() {
   alert(arguments.length); // Outputs: 10
}

var myFunc = function() {
  alert(arguments.length); // Outputs: 10
  otherFunc.apply(this, arguments);
}
myFunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Answer (score 23):

The [splat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/rest_parameters) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Spread_operator) operators are part of ES6, the planned next version of Javascript. So far only Firefox supports them. This code works in FF16+:

```
var arr = ['quick', 'brown', 'lazy'];

var sprintf = function(str, ...args)
{
    for (arg of args) {
        str = str.replace(/%s/, arg);
    }
    return str;
}

sprintf.apply(null, ['The %s %s fox jumps over the %s dog.', ...arr]);
sprintf('The %s %s fox jumps over the %s dog.', 'slow', 'red', 'sleeping');
```

Note the awkard syntax for spread. The usual syntax of `sprintf('The %s %s fox jumps over the %s dog.', ...arr);` is [not yet supported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762363). You can find [an ES6 compatibility table here](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#).

Note also the use of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), another ES6 addition. Using `for...in` for arrays is [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: Normal syntax for spread is now supported in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 9):

There are two methods as of ES2015.

### [The `arguments` Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

This object is built into functions, and it refers to, appropriately, the arguments of a function. It is not technically an array, though, so typical array operations won't work on it. The suggested method is to use `Array.from` or the spread operator to create an array from it.

I've seen other answers mention using `slice`. Don't do that. It prevents optimizations (source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)).

```
Array.from(arguments)
[...arguments]
```

However, I would argue that `arguments` is problematic because it hides what a function accepts as input. An `arguments` function typically is written like this:

```
function mean(){
    let args = [...arguments];
    return args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / args.length;
}
```

Sometimes, the function header is written like the following to document the arguments in a C-like fashion:

```
function mean(/* ... */){ ... }
```

But that is rare.

As for why it is problematic, take C, for example. C is backwards compatible with an ancient pre-ANSI dialect of the language known as K&R C. K&R C allows function prototypes to have an empty arguments list.

```
int myFunction();
/* This function accepts unspecified parameters */
```

ANSI C provides a facility for `varargs` (`...`), and `void` to specify an empty arguments-list.

```
int myFunction(void);
/* This function accepts no parameters */
```

Many people inadvertently declare functions with an `unspecified` arguments list (`int myfunction();`), when they expect the function to take zero arguments. This is technically a bug because the function *will* accept arguments. Any number of them.

A proper `varargs` function in C takes the form:

```
int myFunction(int nargs, ...);
```

And JavaScript actually does have something similar to this.

### [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) / [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

I've already shown you the spread operator, actually.

```
...name
```

It's pretty versatile, and can also be used in a function's argument-list ("rest parameters") to specify varargs in a nicely documented fashion:

```
function mean(...args){
    return args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / args.length;
}
```

Or as a lambda expression:

```
((...args)=>args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / args.length)(1,2,3,4,5); // 3
```

I much prefer the spread operator. It is clean and self-documenting.

Comment: thank you for the updated answer, this post predates ES 2015 so i'm glad you filled in more recent options

Answer (score 8):

The `apply` function takes two arguments; the object `this` will be binded to, and the arguments, represented with an array.

```
some_func = function (a, b) { return b }
some_func.apply(obj, ["arguments", "are", "here"])
// "are"
```

Answer (score 5):

It's called the `splat` operator. You can do it in JavaScript using `apply`:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
var func = function() {
    // debug 
    console.log(arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments);
}
func('a','b','c','d'); // prints 4 which is what I want, then 'a','b','c','d'
func(arr); // prints 1, then 'Array'
func.apply(null, arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 you can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for `varagrs`. This takes the argument list and converts it to an array.

```
function logArgs(...args) {
    console.log(args.length)
    for(let arg of args) {
        console.log(arg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(window) {
  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function() {
    return proxied.apply(window, arguments);
  };
}(this));

alert(13, 37);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample program for calculating sum of integers for variable arguments and array on integers. Hope this helps.

```
var CalculateSum = function(){
    calculateSumService.apply( null, arguments );
}

var calculateSumService = function(){
    var sum = 0;

    if( arguments.length === 1){
        var args = arguments[0];

        for(var i = 0;i<args.length; i++){
           sum += args[i]; 
        }
    }else{
        for(var i = 0;i<arguments.length; i++){
           sum += arguments[i]; 
        }        
    }

     alert(sum);

}


//Sample method call

// CalculateSum(10,20,30);         

// CalculateSum([10,20,30,40,50]);

// CalculateSum(10,20);
```

Comment: Some notes: 1. `var` declares a `function scope` variable. The new `let` and `const` keywords (ES 2015) declare `block scope` variables. Before ES 2015, though, the variables should have still been hoisted to the top of the function as a matter of practice. 2. your function breaks when given 1 integer value because of your erroneous acceptance of an array as an argument (the question asks about varargs; not accepting arrays as arguments): `CalculateSum(6) -> 0`. (continued in next post)

Comment: 3. Don't use debug functions like `alert`. Actually, just don't use `alert/prompt/confirm`, period. Use `console.log` instead when debugging. 4. The function should be `return`ing a value, not `alert`ing it. 5. avoid `PascalCase` unless it refers to a "type" of data. I.e. a class. Use `camelCase` or `under_score` instead. 4. I don't like the way you declare your functions. `var f = function(){ ... }` implies that you want it to *change* at some point, which is probably not your intent. Use the conventional `function name(){ ... }` syntax instead.

Comment: To demonstrate all of these critique points, [here is an improved version](https://pastebin.com/ZUjzRFWt) of the function in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those who were redirected here from [Passing variable number of arguments from one function to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301062/passing-variable-number-of-arguments-from-one-function-to-another) (which should **not** be marked as a duplicate of this question):

If you're trying to pass a variable number of arguments from one function to another, since JavaScript 1.8.5 you can simply call `apply()` on the second function and pass in the `arguments` parameter:

```
var caller = function()
{
    callee.apply( null, arguments );
}

var callee = function()
{
    alert( arguments.length );
}

caller( "Hello", "World!", 88 ); // Shows "3".
```

**Note:** The first argument is the `this` parameter to use. Passing `null` will call the function from the global context, i.e. as a global function instead of the method of some object.

According to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), the ECMAScript 5 specification redefined the `apply()` method to take any "generic array-like object", instead of strictly an Array. Thus, you can directly pass the `arguments` list into the second function.

Tested in Chrome 28.0, Safari 6.0.5, and IE 10. Try it out with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7U2j/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass variable no. of arguments to a function. You can use `apply` to achieve this.

E.g.:

```
var arr = ["Hi","How","are","you"];

function applyTest(){
    var arg = arguments.length;
    console.log(arg);
}

applyTest.apply(null,arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your function to react to an array argument or variable arguments? If the latter, try:

```
var func = function(...rest) {
  alert(rest.length);

  // In JS, don't use for..in with arrays
  // use for..of that consumes array's pre-defined iterator
  // or a more functional approach
  rest.forEach((v) => console.log(v));
};
```

But if you wish to handle an array argument

```
var fn = function(arr) {
  alert(arr.length);

  for(var i of arr) {
    console.log(i);
  }
};
```