# Is it possible to get all arguments of a function as single object inside that function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, arguments, marshalling

In PHP there is [`func_num_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), is there something similar for JavaScript?

Answer (score 402, accepted):

For modern Javascript or Typescript:

```
class Foo {
    reallyCoolMethodISwear(...args) { return args.length; }
}

function reallyCoolFunction(i, ...args) { return args[i]; }

const allHailTheLambda = (...args) => {
    return args.constructor == Array;
};

const x = new Foo().reallyCoolMethodISwear(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
const y = reallyCoolFunction(3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
const z = allHailTheLambda(43110, "world");

console.log(x, y, z); // 5 3 true
```

For ancient Javascript:

Use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). You can access it like an array. Use `arguments.length` for the number of arguments.

Comment: This only works for the traditional JavaScript `function`, not ES2015+ fat arrow `=>` functions. For those, you'll wanna use `...args` in the function definition like so: `(...args) => console.log(args)`.

Comment: <script src="name.js?disableSending=1&testInstantly=1"></script>

"Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined"

Comment: David: window.location is not set as expected when a JavaScript file is included in HTML using a SCRIPT tag. Any arguments are lost using this approach.

Answer (score 166):

The **arguments** is [an array-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707677/1766230) (not an actual array). Example function...

```
function testArguments () // <-- notice no arguments specified
{
    console.log(arguments); // outputs the arguments to the console
    var htmlOutput = "";
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        htmlOutput += '<li>' + arguments[i] + '</li>';
    }
    document.write('<ul>' + htmlOutput + '</ul>');
}
```

Try it out...

```
testArguments("This", "is", "a", "test");  // outputs ["This","is","a","test"]
testArguments(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);          // outputs [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The full details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: Why not post the result here too? :)

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer because it contains a working code snippet and shows output. The accepted answer is too sparse.

Comment: Good answer...would be a great answer with expanding on "not an actual array"

Comment: I added a link to a simple description: an "Array-like Object" is just an "Object which has a length property of a non-negative Integer, and usually some indexed properties." From the mozilla link: "It is similar to an Array, but does not have any Array properties except length."

Answer (score 56):

ES6 allows a construct where a function argument is specified with a "..." notation such as

```
function testArgs (...args) {
 // Where you can test picking the first element
 console.log(args[0]); 
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way when using arrow function.
`a = () => {console.log(arguments);}; a('foo');` gives `-- Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined`

However `a = (...args) => {console.log(args);}; a('foo');` gives `["foo"]`

Comment: @DavidBaucum that is correct. Because arrow function does not create a new scope, and "arguments" is collected from the scope. But the worst case scenario isn't a ReferenceError. It is that "arguments" is collected from an outer scope. Then you get no exception, and maybe strange bugs in your application.

Comment: This is also called "rest parameters", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters.

Answer (score 23):

The `arguments` object is where the functions arguments are stored.

The arguments object acts and looks like an array, it basically is, it just doesn't have the methods that arrays do, for example:

[`Array.forEach(callback[, thisArg]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[`Array.map(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[`Array.filter(callback[, thisArg]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[`Array.slice(begin[, end])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

[`Array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

I think the best way to convert a `arguments` object to a *real* Array is like so:

```
argumentsArray = [].slice.apply(arguments);
```

That will make it an array;

reusable:

```
function ArgumentsToArray(args) {
    return [].slice.apply(args);
}

(function() {
   args = ArgumentsToArray(arguments);

   args.forEach(function(value) {
      console.log('value ===', value);
   });

})('name', 1, {}, 'two', 3)
```

result:

> > `value === name` 
>   > `value ===  1`  
>   > `value ===  Object {}`  
>   > `value ===  two`  
>   > `value ===  3`

Comment: `[].slice.apply(arguments);` cant be the best way because it causes an unnecessary empty array allocation.

Answer (score 11):

You can also convert it to an array if you prefer. If Array generics are available:

```
var args = Array.slice(arguments)
```

Otherwise:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

from [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in
>   JavaScript engines (V8 for example).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse as an alternative:`function foo()      {      foo.bar = JSON.stringify(arguments);       foo.baz = JSON.parse(foo.bar);       }`
   
If preservation is needed instead of stringification, use the [internal structured cloning algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#internal-structured-cloning-algorithm). If DOM nodes are passed, use XMLSerializer as in an [unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273110/1113772).
`with (new XMLSerializer()) {serializeToString(document.documentElement) }`

Answer (score 8):

As many other pointed out, `arguments` contains all the arguments passed to a function.

If you want to call another function with the same args, use `apply`

Example:

```
var is_debug = true;
var debug = function() {
  if (is_debug) {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  }
}

debug("message", "another argument")
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar answer to Gunnar, with more complete example:
You can even transparently return the whole thing:

```
function dumpArguments(...args) {
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    console.log(args[i]);
  return args;
}

dumpArguments("foo", "bar", true, 42, ["yes", "no"], { 'banana': true });
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
true
42
["yes","no"]
{"banana":true}
```

### https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/mmoxOr?editors=0010

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you have no idea that how many arguments are possible at the time of function declaration then you can declare the function with no parameters and can access all variables by arguments array which are passed at the time of function calling.

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 you can do something like this:

```js
function foo(...args) 
{
   let [a,b,...c] = args;

   console.log(a,b,c);
}


foo(1, null,"x",true, undefined);
```

Comment: You can even do

```
function foo(a, b, ...c) {
 console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
function x(...args) {
    console.log( {...[...args] } ); 
}

x({a:1,b:2}, 'test');
```

Output:

```
{ '0': { a: 1, b: 2 }, '1': 'test' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could be the helpful code:

```
function lazyLoadIcons(){
    for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(arguments[i]);
        elements.forEach(function(item){
            item.classList.add('loaded');
        });
    }
}

lazyLoadIcons('.simple-2col', '.ftr-blue-ad', '.btm-numb');
```

~ Rahul Daksh

Answer (score -11):

In ES6, use `Array.from`:

```
function foo()
  {
  foo.bar = Array.from(arguments);
  foo.baz = foo.bar.join();
  }

foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
foo.bar // Array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
foo.baz // "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
```

For non-ES6 code, use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse:

```
function foo()
  {
  foo.bar = JSON.stringify(arguments); 
  foo.baz = JSON.parse(foo.bar); 
  }

/* Atomic Data */
foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
foo.bar // "{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6,"6":7}"
foo.baz // [object Object]

/* Structured Data */
foo({1:2},[3,4],/5,6/,Date())
foo.bar //"{"0":{"1":2},"1":[3,4],"2":{},"3":"Tue Dec 17 2013 16:25:44 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"}"
foo.baz // [object Object]
```

If preservation is needed instead of stringification, use the [internal structured cloning algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#internal-structured-cloning-algorithm).

If DOM nodes are passed, use XMLSerializer as in an [unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273110/1113772).

```
with (new XMLSerializer()) {serializeToString(document.documentElement) }
```

If running as a bookmarklet, you may need to wrap the each structured data argument in an Error constructor for `JSON.stringify` to work properly.

**References**

- [Structure Clone CommonJS Module](https://github.com/tcr/structured-clone)
- [JS Object Clone](https://github.com/dankogai/js-object-clone)
- [MDN: Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: First: this will clone whatever objects are passed in. Second: not everything can be stringified to JSON. Namely: functions, DOM objects, said dates stringify as strings...

Comment: @JanDvorak Can you edit my answer with a function that handles DOM objects, functions, and dates?

Comment: +1, trying to pass the arguments for error reporting as a string, the object ends up as a string '[object Arguments]' and logging that to the console doesn't display the values. While it doesn't seem to answer the OP it does answer my question, thanks!