# What's the best way to make a parameter of a function mandatory?

Tags: function, coffeescript, parameter-passing

In Coffeescript, what's the best way to create a function with mandatory parameters? At the moment, I'm doing this:

```
myFunction: (requiredParam, optionalParam) ->
    unless requiredParam? then throw new Error ...
    ...
```

If I have, say, 5 parameters or even more, it takes quite a lot of time and space to throw an error for each parameter.

Is there a simpler/more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633125/is-it-possible-to-get-all-arguments-of-a-function-as-single-object-inside-that-f) variable inside any function to ensure that the number of actual arguments is not smaller than the number of required arguments.

```
myFunction: (required1, required2, required3, optional1, optional2) ->
  throw new Error("Given #{arguments.length} out of 3 required.") if arguments.length < 3
  # ...
```

Comment: But one more thing, if I wanted to have one of the arguments have a certain type, would there be an easy way to do that?

Comment: Then you have to check the type in the next line, no magic here. Or you can try [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead.