# Javascript Plugin Syntax: How can I correctly pass an anonymous function to an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

***EDIT: I've made a few changes to re-clarify the issue I'm having.***

I have a simple Javascript plugin that I want to add some callback features to as part of its default functionality. Users would be able to specify a function to be called when a certain button is clicked on.

```
// Define option defaults
var defaults = {
  //some other defaults
  onOK: null, //callback functions to be specified here (exists as string)
  onClose: null //callback functions to be specified here (exists as string)
}
```

Normally, this works fine when there's a simple function with no arguments. The option is passed to here:

```
function initializeEvents() {
    //If a close button event is clicked, run this.
    if (this.closeButton) {
      this.closeButton.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this)); //Bind close event to the button
      this.closeButton.addEventListener('click', window[this.options.onClose]); //passed to here
    }
    //If an OK button event is clicked, run this.
    if (this.okButton) {
      this.okButton.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this));
      this.okButton.addEventListener('click', window[this.options.onOK]); //passed to here
    }
  }
```

`window[]` is supposed to become a function call to the appropriate button. **It has come to my attention that I should NOT be using `window[]`.**

**EDIT: However, as @adeneo pointed out, I'm making a BIG mistake here by adding my functions as strings, which simply results in the function becoming `undefined` instead when I have to add it to an event listener.**

I've tried using an anonymous function, but I'm still not getting the function to work:

```
var callbackModal = new raModal({
            content: '<div>You clicked on the Callback button. This shows the popup, but has a custom callback function, called when the user clicks OK and/or Close.</div>',
            onOK:{function(){
                    okCallback('4');
                 }
            },
            onClose: "closeCallback",
            closeButtonText: "Close"
        });
        callbackModal.open();
```

So, my question has changed to: 
**How can I properly add my anonymous functions from the defaults?**

[Link to a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/47bnbsqp/) You'll notice that while the Close button works as intended (with `closeCallback` printing the console.log message), the OK button calling `okCallback(num)` does nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you add functions as strings?  
The issue is that you're expecting a reference to a function, and when you add the parentheses you call the function and return the result, which in your case is just `undefined`. If you really need to pass arguments, you can use an anonymous function, but then you'd have to expect references, not strings

Comment: @adeneo  Strings seemed to work at the time, because otherwise I was running into a syntax error. I tried anonymous functions, 
but all I got was `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`.

Comment: Whatever floats your goat, I'm just telling you that you're not doing it correctly. It's a really bad idea to pass the function names as strings, and then use `window["functionName"]` to call those functions.

Comment: @adeneo Yup, I definitely know now that that's not the correct way to do it! Thanks for pointing that out. ;) 
I've edited my post with your information as well as what I've tried.

Comment: Maybe it's easier if I just show you -> https://jsfiddle.net/cw1Lscsw/

Comment: @adeneo I'm afraid I'm still lost. Care to add more details in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to bind the callbacks to the button in `initializeEvents()` using the risky `window[]` implementation, it's much easier to simply append them after the button object after they're constructed.

I made two additional functions to add the event listeners for the OK and Close buttons:

```
  function closeCallback(callback){
    $(".ra-close").click(callback);
  }
  function okCallback(callback){
    $(".ra-ok").click(callback);
  }
```

And inside the `buildOut()` function, after everything is done, add the calls to the event listeners, using our custom option as the argument, which can be an anonymous function now!

```
closeCallback(this.options.onClose);
okCallback(this.options.onOK);
```

There was an additional utility function that extended user options to the new modal, but didn't track `null` values properly. I removed an `if` statement that checked for those, seeing as we had them as part of the `defaults` variable.

```
  // Utility method to extend defaults with user options
  function extendDefaults(source, properties) {
    var property;
    for (property in properties) {
        source[property] = properties[property];
    }
    return source;
  }
```

[Here's the updated JSFiddle with the corrected plugin code.](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/4motckm6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to JavaScript functions without having a parameter name on the function's signature. This should be a workaround for your problem.

See [Is it possible to get all arguments of a function as single object inside that function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633125/is-it-possible-to-get-all-arguments-of-a-function-as-single-object-inside-that-f)