# Get function arguments names and values dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function like this:

```
function myfunction(text: string,num: number) {
   console.log( args_namesValues );
}
```

I would like to get as a result after calling

```
myFunction("myText", 3)
```

To output the following or similar:

```
{text:"myText",num:3}
```

What can be the code behind *args_namesValues*.

Comment: `console.log({ text, num })`?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633125/is-it-possible-to-get-all-arguments-of-a-function-as-single-object-inside-that-f

Comment: arguments will give only the values (seems also deprecated)

Comment: What would your actual use case be? Not clear why you can define parameters but not use them later when they are already known

Comment: the reason is I want to transfer the function name and arguments (name and values) to the server for processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log({text, num});
```

Check ES6 property shorthand notation
http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand

Comment: If you are working on the browser side, please be mind that shorthand notation does not work with IE11.

Answer (score 0):

My question was not clear... sorry
I found a solution via Proxies, see http://2ality.com/2015/10/intercepting-method-calls.html

The following function allows to trace method calls/to hook it (thats what I wanted ...)

```
function traceMethodCalls(obj) {
    let handler = {
        get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            const origMethod = target[propKey];
            return function (...args) {
                let result = origMethod.apply(this, args);
                console.log(propKey + JSON.stringify(args)
                    + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                return result;
            };
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log({text: text, num:num})
```

If you want to get parameter names dynamically you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924463/1118978)

Comment: yes, I meant dynamically. changed in the title/subject. I look at the link

Comment: nice, but I am not sure if it is possible to get values