# How to get access to function args

Tags: javascript

I came across this piece of code ... where `args` is interpreted to `fn` `args object` ... this is really confusing for me, and I couldn't get it

```
function memoize(fn) {
    return function(...args) {
        fn.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

How does the inner function understand that `args` passed to it belongs to `fn`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633125/is-it-possible-to-get-all-arguments-of-a-function-as-single-object-inside-that-f

Comment: @CertainPerformance from my understanding, accessing `arguments` inside the outer function should return `fn` arg .... bu tI want to get access to argments of `fn`