# How can javascript skip passing a parameter for a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I've been learning node.js, and I've found two code fragments like this:

Fragment 1:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile("content.txt", "utf8", (err, msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
})
```

Fragment 2:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile("content.txt", (err, msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
})
```

They have only one difference that *Fragment 1* passed 'utf8' as the second parameter while *Fragment 2* skips to pass it. And although they have different results, both of them can function normally without a syntax error.

So I wonder how a javascript method is able to skip to pass the parameter? And how can I define a method/function like this?

Comment: The count of arguments is optional when calling a function. Usually functions check (such functions you can pass a varying count of arguments) the arguments by type, and then execute alternative code depending on the type of a specific argument.

Comment: The function will determine the [arity](https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arity.html) of the arguments, and test to see if the second argument is a function or not, and then proceed based on that information.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for your answer, you answer solved my confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect in your own code by determining the [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) within your method. This might be as simple as just checking the number of arguments, or it might be that you need to check the *type* of each/some argument(s)

An example:

```js
function myArityAwareFunction(){
    if(arguments.length == 2)
        console.log("2 arguments", ...arguments)
    else if(arguments.length == 3)
        console.log("3 arguments", ...arguments)
    else
        throw ("This method must be called with 2 or 3 arguments");
}


myArityAwareFunction("foo","bar");
myArityAwareFunction("foo","bar","doo");
myArityAwareFunction("This will fail");
```

Comment: I thought javascript must have implemented some nice syntax for us, but I never thought like this easy with just a bunch of if and else if, but would things get more complicated when there comes quite a lot parameters?

Comment: @Paper_Folding there are also optional arguments with a default: https://jsfiddle.net/876Lv5pf/

Comment: @Paper_Folding please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633125/is-it-possible-to-get-all-arguments-of-a-function-as-single-object-inside-that-f

Answer (score 0):

With arrow function:

```js
const fn = (...args) => {
  console.log(args.length);
  if (args.length < 2) {
    throw Error('missing arguments');
  } else if (args.length === 2) {
    /* ... */
  } else if (args.length === 3) {
    /* ... */
  } else {
    /* ... */
  }
};
```

or with `switch` block

```js
const fn = (...args) => {
  console.log(args.length);
  switch(args.length) {
    case 0: /* ... */ break;
    case 1: /* ... */ break;
    /* ... */
    default: /* ... */ break;
  }
};
```

But it's much better to validate argument type rather than do something depend on `args.length`

So for your example with the `fs` code could look like this:

```js
const readFile = (...args) => {
  if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
    /* ... */
  } else {
    throw TypeError('Path must be a string');
  }
  if (typeof args[1] === 'string') {
    /* ... */
    if (typeof args[2] === 'function') {
      /* ... */
    } else {
      throw TypeError('Callback must be a function');
    }
  } else if (typeof args[1] === 'function') {
    /* ... */
  } else {
    throw TypeError('Callback must be a function');
  }
};
```

```js
readFile({}); // TypeError: path must be a string
readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', {}); // TypeError: Callback must be a function
readFile('test.txt', {}); // TypeError: Callback must be a function

readFile('test.txt', () => {}); // success
readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', () => {}); // success
```