# Dealing with non-saveable values in Backbone

Tags: javascript, database, backbone.js

Is there a standard way to deal with non-saveable values in Backbone.

e.g.

```
MyModel = Backbone.extend(Backbone.Model, {
    initialize: function () {
        this.set({'inches': this.get('mm') / 25});
    }
})
```

If I call save() on this model it will throw an error as there is no corresponding database field for `inches`. I can think of a few ways to fix this, but am wondering if there's a tried and tested approach generally best used for this?

At the moment my preferred solution is to extend Backbone's `toJSON` method and to allow passing of a boolean parameter `dontCleanup` to allow for it to still return all the model's values (including the non saveable ones) when it's needed e.g. for passing to a template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like Peter Lyon's idea. I've thought about that a few times, but never actually put it in place. For all the ways that I have handled this, though, here are my two favorites:

- Non-"attribute" values
- View Models

#### Non-Attribute Values

This one is simple: don't store the values you need in the model's standard attributes. Instead, attach it directly to the object:

```
myModel.someValue = "some value";
```

The big problem here is that you don't get all of the events associated with calling `set` on the model. So I tend to wrap this up in a method that does everything for me. For example, a common method I put on models is `select` to say that this model has been selected:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  select: function(){
    if (!this.selected){
      this.selected = true;
      this.trigger("change:selected", this, this.selected);
    }
  }
});
```

In your case, I'm not sure this would be a good approach. You have data that needs to be calculated based on the values that are in your attributes already.

For that, I tend to use view models.

#### View models.

The basic idea is that you create a backbone model that is persist-able, as you normally would. But the you come along and create another model that inherits from your original one and adds all the data that you need.

There are a very large number of ways that you can do this. Here's what might be a very simple version:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.Extend({ ... });

MyViewModel = function(model){
  var viewModel = Object.create(model);

  viewModel.toJSON = function(){
    var json = model.toJSON();
    json.inches = json.mm / 25;
    return json;
  };

  return viewModel;
});
```

The big benefit of wrapping this with `Object.create` is that you now have a prototypal inheritance situation, so all of your standard functionality from the model is still in place. We've just overridden the `toJSON` method on the view model, so that it returns the JSON object with the `inches` attribute.

Then in a view that needs this, you would wrap your model in the initialize function:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model = MyViewModel(this.model);
  },
```

render: function(){
    var data = this.model.toJSON(); // returns with `inches`
  }
});

You could call `new MyViewModel(this.model)` if you want, but that's not going to do anything different, in the end, because we're explicitly returning an object instance from the `MyViewModel` function.

When your view's render method calls `toJSON`, you'll get the `inches` attribute with it.

Of course, there are some potential memory concerns and performance concerns with this implementation, but those can be solved easily with some better code for the view model. This quick and dirty example should get you down the path, though.

Comment: Having mulled this over I'm a) attracted to it as it's pretty flexible and I could have many variants based on the initial model in a very decoupled and maintainable way; but b) As it uses prototypal inheritance maybe the performance hit won't be all that bad, but it does add a lot more objects to my app which, with 300+ records being handled, is a worry. I'll try and think of a way of combining yours and @Peter Lyons approaches

Comment: Extending a model to fit a specific view's needs through a ViewModel and still letting the original model unaffected for general use, is a very elegant maneuver. Nice!

Comment: If you use view models, how might you access the value of inches outside of a view? (e.g. if you needed that value in a collection)

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it. Define your `Model` `defaults` as your valid schema and then return only the subset of `this.attributes` that is valid during `toJSON`.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    foo: 42,
    bar: "bar"
  },

  toJSON: function () {
    var schemaKeys = _.keys(this.defaults);
    var allowedAttributes = {};
    _.each(this.attributes, function (value, key) {
    if (_.include(schemaKeys, key)) {
      allowedAttributes[key] = value;
    }
    return allowedAttributes;
  }
});
```

Note that `_.pick` would make the code a bit shorter once you have underscore 1.3.3 available. I haven't seen a "tried and tested" convention in my travels through the backbone community, and since backbone leaves so many options open, sometimes conventions don't emerge, but we'll see what this stackoverflow question yields.

Comment: I liek this, apart from atht it means I need to keep the model schema up to date with my database schema (which is perhaps not unreasonable). I might adapt this so that in initialize if defaults doesn't exist yet it is created using the keys in the object passed inn to the model

Comment: Overwriting the `toJSON` method seems to be a popular approach.

However, in this case, by using the defaults hash as the persisted schema, you may run into issues if you want to set defaults for a non-persisted attribute.

Perhaps a separate attribute like `schemaKeys` would be better: `schemaKeys: [ 'foo', 'bar' ]`

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with *non-persisted attributes* in Backbone.js has been doing my head in for a while, particularly since I've started using ember/ember-data, which handles the various situations through computed properties, ember-data attributes, or controllers.

Many solutions suggest customising the `toJSON` method. However, some popular Backbone plugins (particularly those that deal with nested models), implement their own `toJSON` method, and make a call to `Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON` to obtain an object representation of a model's attributes. So by overwriting the `toJSON` method in a model definition, you'll lose some (potentially crucial) features of those plugins.

The best I've come up with is to include an `excludeFromJSON` array of keys in the model definition, and overwrite the `toJSON` method on `Backbone.Model.prototype` itself:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var json = _.clone(this.attributes),
      excludeFromJSON = this.excludeFromJSON;
  if(excludeFromJSON) {
    _.each(excludeFromJSON, function(key) {
      delete json[key];
    });
  }
  return json;
};

MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  excludeFromJSON: [
    'inches'
  ]
});
```

In this way, you'll only have to define the non-persisted keys (if you forget to do so, you'll soon be reminded when your server throws an error!). `toJSON` will behave as normal if no `excludeFromJSON` property is present.

---

In your case, `inches` is a computed property, derived from `mm`, so it makes sense to implement this as a method on your model (ensuring that the value for inches is correct when mm is changed):

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  inches: function() {
    return this.get('mm') / 25;
  }
});
```

However, this has the downside of being accessed differently to everyother attribute. Ideally you'll want to keep it consistent with accessing other attributes. This can be achieved by [extending the default `get` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6696112/783009):

```
var getMixin = {
  get: function(attr) {
    if(typeof this[attr] == 'function') {
      return this[attr]();
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.get.call(this, attr);
  }
};

MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  inches: function() {
    return this.get('mm') / 25;
  }
});
_.extend(MyModel.prototype, getMixin);
```

Which will let you do:

```
new MyModel().get('inches');
```

This approach doesn't touch the underlying `attributes` hash, meaning that `inches` will not appear in the `toJSON` representation, *unless* you `set` the value of `inches` later on, in which case you'll need something like the `excludeFromJSON` array.

If you have the need to `set` the `inches` value, you may also want to listen for changes and adjust the value of `mm`:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.on('change:inches', this.changeInches, this);
  },

  inches: function() {
    return this.get('mm') / 25;
  },

  changeInches: function() {
    this.set('mm', this.attributes.inches * 25);
  }
});
_.extend(MyModel.prototype, getMixin);
```

See the [complete example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ajinuy/1/edit).

It's also worth noting that [the (official?) purpose of the `toJSON` method](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2134) has recently been redefined as preparing a model for syncing with a server. For this reason, calling `toJSON` should always return only the "persistable" (or "saveable") attributes.