# Looping through unknown number of array arguments

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to loop through several array arguments passed. 
For example: [1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]
If I pass it to a function, how would I have a function loop inside each argument (any number of arrays can be passed) ?

I want to use a for loop here.

Comment: within the function you'd iterate over `arguments`, and for each argument, you'd iterate over the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Comment: var args = arguments;
          for(i = 0; i < args.length,i++)
            var l = args[i].length;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for this:

```
for(var arg = 0; arg < arguments.length; ++ arg)
{
    var arr = arguments[arg];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++ i)
    {
         var element = arr[i];

         /* ... */
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use forEach, as below:

```
'use strict';

    function doSomething(p1, p2) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
        }, this);
    }

    doSomething(1);
    doSomething(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in `arguments` keyword which will contain the `length` of how many arrays you have.  Use that as a basis to loop through each array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loopThroughArguments(){
    // It is always good to declare things at the top of a function, 
    // to quicken the lookup!
    var i = 0,
        len = arguments.length;

    // Notice that the for statement is missing the initialization.
    // The initialization is already defined, 
    // so no need to keep defining for each iteration.
    for( ; i < len; i += 1 ){

        // now you can perform operations on each argument,
        // including checking for the arguments type,
        // and even loop through arguments[i] if it's an array!
        // In this particular case, each argument is logged in the console.
        console.log( arguments[i] );
    }

};
```