# Insert text into an undetermined number of spans, For Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have this span:

```
<span class="spanComments" cols="100" rows="5"></span>
```

being called by this :

```
<a href="#" rel="@currentShowing.ShowingGUID" class="showComments noprint" id="comments-sendlink" onclick="showComments()">View Comments</a>
```

using this function:

```
    function showComments() {
    for (var arg = 0; arg < arg.length; ++arg) {
        var arr = arguments[arg];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++ i) {
            document.getElementById("spanComments").innerHTML = "This is comment #" + arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I used this SO question as my basis to no avail:
[JavaScript For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210312/looping-through-unknown-number-of-array-arguments)

I'm not getting my span to populate anything (it's completely empty)
I have tested my showComments() and it works (prior to me entering the for loop) and it worked.

I'm new to JavaScript, so I wouldn't be surprised if it were something really easy that I might have overlooked.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `arg` in your program? `arg < arg.length`?!?

Comment: I was modelling it after the other SO question

Comment: `arg` is defined twice, first you use that name for the iterator, and then you seem to have an array with the same name, which isn't possible.

Comment: I use arr not arg for the second for loop

Comment: If both loops work fine your span will just take the last value.

Comment: The second loop never runs because the first loop is completely wrong.

Comment: Okay, how do I fix it?

Comment: I mean come on `var arg = 0; arg < arg.length; ++arg` , how would a zero have length ?

Comment: What do you expect for output?  Your code appears to overwrite rather than append comments.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I would like to add to (in this case).  "comments #{0}", comment Number.
So 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple problems here: you are iterating over args before it is defined, `arguments` should be what you are iterating over in your top most loop. Additionally, you are overwriting the same item each time (I assume there are multiple `spanComments`). I suggest changing to `class="spanComments"` and using the following:

```
function showComments() {
   var comments = document.querySelectorAll(".spanComments");
   for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
      comments[i].innerHTML = "This is comment #" + i;
   }
}
```

Comment: i changed it to class instead of id, and used your function.  i'm still getting an empty span

Comment: @KevinFischer Can you clarify how you are calling `showComments`?

Comment: i'll post the <a> on here.  one sec

Comment: It looks like you really aren't using arguments at all (only the event is passed here), I've updated my answer

Comment: As  @Samurai noted, ther original code only displays the last value. This snippet appears to do the same.  So I don't understand the point of looping ... just display the final comment.

Comment: it actually doesn't.  the string changes "This is comment #1", "This is comment #2", "This is comment #3", etc.
I'm going to be using this as a basis for another project and I had to figure out how to loop into a span