# ([ numbers ], numbers) as function parameter, how to get numbers from outside of [ ]?

Tags: javascript

```
function a(b) {

 var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(b);
 console.log(array);

 var array_two = ???;
 console.log(array_two);

}

a([1, 2, 3], 1, 2);
```

`console.log(array);` gives me output `[1, 2, 3]` as expected.

What I want to achieve here is getting `[1, 2]` - numbers after [ ], joined as array. I thought that `b[number]` would solve the problem. `b[0]` - array, `b[1]` - first number after array, `b[2]` - second number after array but apparently it does not work like that. Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: `var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(b);` why do you do this? `b` is already an array when you pass it in. It seems like you wanted to use the `arguments` object, not the first parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through unknown number of array arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210312/looping-through-unknown-number-of-array-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either change your function to

```
function a(array,firstArgAfterArray,secondArgAfterArray)
```

or you can get the first and seconds args after the array like that

```
arguments[1] , arguments[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Rest parameter` at `a` function, where `...c` is set as last parameter to `a` function, and can be accessed within `a` function body as an array having identifier `c`. See [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper)

```js
function a(b, ...c) {

 var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(b);
 console.log(array, c);
}

console.log(
  a([1, 2, 3], 1, 2)
  , a([1,2,3], "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all given parameters as an array with the predefined variable *arguments*. But in this case you have to remove the first element (because its array_one):

```
var array_two = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments