# Passing array index as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a piece of code as follows.

```
var aMessages = new Array();
aMessages["gender"] = new Array();
aMessages["gender"]["blank"] = new Array();
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Default"] = "Please select the gender of the person being registered on the site.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Self"] = "Please select your gender.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Son"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Daughter"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Brother"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Sister"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Friend"] = "Please select your friend's gender.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Relative"] = "Please select your relative's gender.";
aMessages["gender"]["invalid"] = "Please choose relevant gender.";

function displayMessage(field, errorCase){
    console.log(errorCase, field, "here");
    console.log(aMessages[field][errorCase]);
}

err = 'invalid';
displayMessage("gender", err);
```

So I pass the field and error case to the function and the function do some thing, for now let assume it prints the messages. It was fine for one level i.e. `gender (field) -> err (errorcase)`. But how can I pass index of index in parameter.

Is there any workaround for this. Also suggest any other good approch for it.

Comment: FYI, you really should be using objects, not arrays. Arrays are supposed to be used with numerical indexes.

Comment: Is that what you search for? http://jsbin.com/ESIKuxE/1/edit, EDIT, wrong link

Comment: @JonathandeM. Yes somewhat like this. But can we make it dynamic like there might be more than 2 levels

Comment: @FelixKling True. But the messages are used by many other functions and will not be able to change it.

Comment: Mmh, just replace `new Array()` with `{}` ;) You cannot use any of the array functions anyway because they don't work with "normal" properties.

Comment: @FelixKling ok will do that, so after that how can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: @JonathandeM. what is the use of `argv = [].slice.call(arguments);` in your code

Comment: @jimy Transform the pseudo array `argument` to a true array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most flexible way would be to use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), as described in this question: [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141530/231573).

However, a common javascript practice is to use an object literal for the sake of readability and also for not having to worry about the order of the arguments.  You can see many examples of this in the jQuery UI API, like this one: [.effect( options )](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/#effect-options).

Here is a start ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQeew/)):

```
function displayMessage(field, errorCase) {
    if (typeof errorCase === "string") {
        console.log(errorCase, field, "here");
        console.log(aMessages[field][errorCase]);
    } else {
        // You should ensure the errorCase object literal has these properties before accessing them
        console.log(errorCase.err, field, "there");
        console.log(errorCase.relation, field, "there again");
        console.log(aMessages[field][errorCase.err][errorCase.relation]);
    }
}

displayMessage("gender", {
    err: "blank",
    relation: "Sister"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This offers something like what you want ?

```
var aMessages = new Array();
aMessages["gender"] = new Array();
aMessages["gender"]["blank"] = new Array();
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Default"] = "Please select the gender of the person being registered on the site.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Self"] = "Please select your gender.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Son"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Daughter"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Brother"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Sister"] = "Gender of the member is required for registration.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Friend"] = "Please select your friend's gender.";
aMessages["gender"]["blank"]["Relative"] = "Please select your relative's gender.";
aMessages["gender"]["invalid"] = "Please choose relevant gender.";

function displayMessage(field, errorCase){
    console.log(errorCase, field, "here");

    var argc = arguments.length;
    if(argc >= 3) {
      console.log(aMessages[field][errorCase][arguments[2]]);
    }
    else {
      console.log(aMessages[field][errorCase]);
    }
}

err = 'invalid';
displayMessage("gender", err);

err = 'blank';
displayMessage("gender", err, "Daughter");
```