# Passing Variable Number of arguments in javascript function argument-list

Tags: javascript, function, variadic-functions

Can I pass a variable number of arguments into a Javascript function? I have little knowledge in JS. I want to implement something like the following:

```
 function CalculateAB3(data, val1, val2, ...)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: yes you can :-) heres a good tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: You can pass multiple arguments, but the better way is that you can pass an object or an array instead

Comment: yes...you can pass any number of parameters...http://javascript.info/tutorial/arguments

Comment: Javascript supports passing of multiple parameters through function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters in your function and access them via [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) variable. Here is an example of function which returns the sum of all parameters you passed in it

```
var sum = function () {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        res += parseInt(arguments[i]);
    }
    return res;
 }
```

You can call it as follows:

```
sum(1, 2, 3); // returns 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer to your question, surely you can

But personally I would like to pass a object rather than `n` numbers of parameters

Example:

```
function CalculateAB3(obj)
{
    var var1= obj.var1 || 0; //if obj.var1 is null, 0 will be set to var1 
    //rest of parameters
}
```

Here `||` is logical operator for more info visit http://codepb.com/null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript/

A [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript) is a good read

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make it. Use variable `arguments` like there:

```
function test() {
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i])
  }
}
```