# Constructing of an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist

I'd like to make an array how this:

```
var varOne, varTwo, varThree; // (If vars are == null don't insert on array)
var array = [];
array = [
    {"ONE": varOne},
    {"TWO": varTwo},
    {"THREE": varThree}
    ];
```

The inputs to the array I'd like to do only when `varOne`, `varTwo` and `varThree` are other than `null`

Best regards

Comment: You want to filter the variables if there are not `null`?

Comment: What is the question here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to filter when the variables are `null`, for example, if `varOne==null` the array will be `[{"TWO": varTwo},{"THREE": varThree}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty natural to use `if` blocks for this:

```
if (varOne !== null) {
    array.push({ONE: varOne});
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to dfsqs answer, you could create a function whichtakes any number of arguments and uses an iterator to perform a null check on each one. (ie use the arguments object - see [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function))
This code will give you an array of [{"1":"x"},{"2":"z"}]

```
function foo() {
 var array = [];
 var counter = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i]){ 
       counter++;
       var map = {};
       map[counter] = arguments[i]
       array.push(map);
        //document.write(i + " " + arguments[i] + " ");
    }   
 }
 return array;
}

var varOne="x"; 
var varTwo=null; 
var varThree="z"; // (If vars are == null don't insert on array)

var array = foo(varOne,varTwo,varThree); //could be as many variables as you like
//document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```