# passing arguments AND a callback function

Tags: javascript

I can write a simple function that uses a helper function to do work:

```
function calculate(a,b,fn){
    return fn(a,b);
}

function sum(args){
    total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        total += arguments[i];
        }
    return total;
}
console.log(calculate(15,8,sum));
```

As it's constructed now, the initial function will take 2 arguments and a function as its parameters. **How do I configure it to accept ANY number of arguments plus a function?** I tried:

```
function calculate(fn, args){
    args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return fn(args);
}
```

but in that scenario, invoking:

```
calculate(sum, 14, 5, 1, 3);
```

is the equivalent of invoking:

```
 sum([14, 5, 1, 3]);
```

What's the proper way of accomplishing this?

Comment: This might be of help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). It lets you pass an array and it turns each member of the array as each argument to the function being called.

```
function calculate(fn){
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return fn.apply(this, args);
}
```

Another example, if you have an array and you want to find out the highest number in it.

```
function max(array) {
    // Math.max takes separate arguments, turn each member of the array 
    // into a separate argument
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
}
```

Or using `calculate`:

```
calculate(Math.max, 3, 2, 4, 7, 23, 3, 6); // 23
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is wrapping the arguments in an array or an object and iterating through it inside the function.