# JavaScript function that takes multiple sets of arguments

Tags: javascript

I will pass to a fuction mutiple sets of argumentes like this:

```
Myfunction(var1,var2)(var3,var4)(var5);
```

But i only know how to get the first set of aguments like this:

```
function Myfunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    alert(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

and it will return `var1, var2`

How can i get the other set of aguments (var3,var4)(var5) etc... ?

My reference: [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Comment: `Myfunction(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5);`?

Comment: or is myFunction returns another function?

Comment: What do you mean, "multiple sets of arguments"?

Comment: That example of how you call `MyFunction` is only valid if it returns a function (which it doesn't), and if *that* function also returns a function.  It's not clear what you're trying to do or why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you *think* this code is doing:

```
Myfunction(var1,var2)(var3,var4)(var5)
```

But this is invoking *three* functions.  Not *one*.  To illustrate where your arguments would be available:

```
function MyFunction() {
    // var1 and var2 are available here, because they were passed to this function
    return function() {
        // var3 and var4 were passed to THIS function
        return function() {
            // var5 was passed to THIS function
        }
    }
}
```

You can't access `var3`, `var4`, or `var5` in `MyFunction` because they weren't passed to that function.  They were passed to the function(s) being *returned* by that function.

If you want to pass all of these arguments to `MyFunction` then do so:

```
MyFunction(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);
```

Then they would all be available:

```
function MyFunction() {
    // var1, var2, var3, var4, and var5 are all available here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you want is probably as simple as that

```
function myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) {
    // use all your arguments here
}
```

If you want to have a pair of argument you could just send arrays as parameter like: `myfunction([0, 1], [34, 21], [2,7])`

To archieve a function call like you did you would need to do something like (see below), but that is totally insane.

```
function myFunction(arg1, arg2) {
    return function(arg3, arg4) {
        return function(arg5) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments you can supply to a function in JavaScript is effectively unlimited (no limit is defined in the spec, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept) indicates that Chrome has a limit of 65535).

The arity of a function is the number of parameters specified in its definition. In JavaScript the arity of a function can be safely ignored when performing an invocation. You may supply as may arguments are you like.

You can get hold of all the arguments in the `arguments` array-like object implicitly associated with every function invocation, or if you are using ES2015, then you can use the spread operator (as I do below).

**The second feature** of your question is that you are spreading a single larger operation across multiple invocations. This is known as currying and is a somewhat more advanced technique. In JavaScript you can leverage closures to achieve it.

This example may help you:

```
function add(...args1) {
  if(!args1.length) {
    return sum(args1);
  }

  return (...args2) => {
    if(!args2.length) {
      return sum(args1.concat(args2));
    }

    return add.apply(null, args1.concat(args2));        
  };
}

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((p,c) => p+c,0);
}

console.assert(add(1,2)(3)(4)() === 10, '1+2+3+4 should be 10');
```