# Pushing numbers into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to do something simple, but not sure what I am doing wrong.

I simply want to call a function with number arguments and push those numbers into a new array...

```js
function someFunction(n){
  var newArray = new Array(n);
  for(var i=0; i < n.length; i++){
    newArray += n[i];
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(someFunction(3,5,4,5));
```

Here is [bin](http://jsbin.com/hocazodelu/edit?js,console)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function take a look at this - here is explained how to deal with a variable number of arguments, which is, if I understand good, your main issue. And also at this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp - here is how to push elements to a javascript array.

Comment: Start with MDN; you have a problem on nearly every line here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get those numbers into the array for you.  And it will do it for unlimited numbers supplied: **https://jsfiddle.net/a9umss9a/3/**

```
function someFunction(){
  var newArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    newArray.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(someFunction(3,5,4,5));

console.log(someFunction(3,5,4,5,100,200,300,400,500));
```

Comment: Thanks gfrobenius, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Why have a named arg `n` if you're not using it? Why use the `Array` constructor instead of `var newArray = []`?

Comment: Don't have to.  Just using the OP code to get what he wanted.  I made the changes tho, thanks @Mathletics

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as a one-liner:

```
function toArray() {
    return [].slice.call(arguments);
}
```

---

Here's the breakdown of issues in your code.

```
function someFunction(n){ // this captures the FIRST argument as n
  var newArray = new Array(n); // this creates a new Array of length n (in your case, 3, which is not accurate
  for(var i=0; i < n.length; i++){ // n is a number and has no length property
    newArray += n[i]; // newArray is an array, so you must push to it; the + operator makes no sense
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: You see, sometimes sarcasm does the trick. Thanks for the great detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

someFunction requires 1 input of type array, not 4 inputs:

```
function someFunction(n){
  var newArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i < n.length; i++){
    newArray.push(n[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(someFunction([3,5,4,5]));
```

Comment: True. But doing it this way makes the function pointless.  You could just replace the guts of the function with `function someFunction(n){ return n; }` and get the same thing. The OP wanted this format: `someFunction(3,5,4,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with direct building of an array.

```js
function someFunction() {
    return Array.apply(null, arguments);
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(someFunction(3, 5, 4, 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```