# How do you generate a function that warns about not enough arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, anonymous

If you are dynamically generating functions with varying number of required arguments, how do you **determine** ***if*** the future **number of** supplied **arguments** to the function call ***are enough*** and/or how do you make sure your function **warn**s **for** / about required, or **missing** number of **arguments**?

The anonymous function may have a structure body as simple as:

```
fucntion( x, y, z ) {
        /*test for the arguments supplied*/
    if( notEnoughArguments )
        /*exit the function and return a warning*/   
        /*otherwise, say ...*/
     return x*y*x
    }
```

The problem: you don't know beforehand how many arguments will a certain function require, and you're not sure how many arguments will be available/supplied at the time of the function call.

Comment: You can check for `arguments.length < 3` to makes sure, ad least three arguments were provided. You can `throw new Error('missing arguments')` to throw an Exception and abort or log to console, if you don`t want to abort.

Comment: maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function

Comment: ok, it was just a question.

Comment: To me it is a very valid question and different from the proposed duplicate.

Comment: if i would not like the question, i would dv it, if i think it's a dupe, i could close it directly. anyway `arguments.length` is a property of function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguments object inside the function. For e.g. arguments.length will provide number of arguments passed into the function. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) length vs. the [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

In functions...

> The length property specifies the number of arguments expected by the
>   function.

The arguments object is an array like object, that contains all arguments passed to the function.

```js
function multi(x, y, z) {
  if(arguments.length < multi.length) {
    console.log('not enough arugments');
    return null;
  }

  return x * y * x
}

multi();

console.log(multi(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: That'd be great, but unless there is a way to generate named functions the functions generated will be anonymous.

Comment: You can always add a name to a function - even anonymous ones. `var a = function b();` -> the internal name of the function is `b`. It works in callbacks as well -> `.map(function m() {})`.

Comment: You might want to tell mdn's [arguments article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) about that.

Comment: @BekimBacaj - feel free to supply your own references. However, you are digressing. Does the answer helps you in your problem or not? If not, why?