# Node.js return object keys based on its value

Tags: javascript, node.js

In **nodejs 8.10** I want a function to return a different object depending on parameters. Is there any simple way to include or not a key based on its value?

Example

```
// I do not like this solution, there is a 2 line body
// `c` may be undefined or a string (for example)
const f = (a, b, c) => {
  if (c) return ({ a, b, c });
  else return { a, b }
}
```

Can we do a simple return with `c` included or excluded based on its value?
I expect something like this:

```
// I expect this kind of solution.
const f = (a, b, c) => ({ a, b, ___????___ })
```

Comment: You could use `arguments`.
Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no way to do that but you can:

```
const f = (a, b, c) => (c ? { a, b, c } : { a, b });
```

or

```
const f = (a, b, c) => {
  const result = { a, b };
  if (c) result.c = c;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: First solution duplicates `a` and `b`, second one is still a 2 lines answer. This is not exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.