# Passing variable number of arguments from one function to another

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

I can use `arguments` to get a variable number of arguments within a function, but how can I pass them to another function without knowing its prototype?

```
function show(foo, bar) { window.alert(foo+' '+bar); }
function run(f) { f(arguments); } // not correct, what to do?
run(show, 'foo', 'bar');
```

Note: I cannot guarantee the number of arguments needed for the function `f` that is passed to `run`. Meaning, even though the example shown has 2 arguments, it could be 0-infinite, so the following **isn't** appropriate:

```
function run(f) { f(arguments[1], arguments[2]); }
```

Comment: I disagree, as you can see, `show` has defined arguments, it does not use `arguments`. I have already tried `apply` that way with no luck.

Comment: Well, as you have noticed by now, `apply` is the only way to do this, therefore it *is* a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, except the way `arguments` used was entirely different and ultimately the point of the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The main way to pass a programmatically generated set of arguments to a function is by using the function's 'apply' method.

```
function show(foo, bar) {
  window.alert(foo+' '+bar);
}
function run(f) {
  // use splice to get all the arguments after 'f'
  var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1);
  f.apply(null, args);
}

run(show, 'foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: For Posterity, if the function is an object method and needs to keep it's context, pass the `this` object instead of `null` with `f.apply(this, args);`.

Answer (score 6):

You can in fact do this with apply, if I understand your question correctly:

```
function show(foo, bar) { window.alert(foo+' '+bar); }
function run(f, args) { f.apply(null,args); } 
run(show, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Comment: The problem with that, I already have a framework setup using `arguments` and don't want to switch all the calls to use arrays. On that same not, I can try converting `arguments` from an object to an array and pass that.

Comment: Take a look at the solution from @Logan then, seems like it will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the apply function.. here is how u do it:

```
function variableFunction1()  
    {  

   alert("variableFunction1 arguments length: " + arguments.length);  

   // calls second varargs function keeping current 'this'.  
   variableFunction2.apply(this, arguments);  
}  

function variableFunction2()  
{  

   alert("variableFunction2 arguments length: " + arguments.length);  
}  

variableFunction1('a','b','c');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkGp2/3)**

Answer (score 0):

In your example to pass variable arguments to show this works

```
function show(foo, bar) { window.alert(foo+' '+bar); }
function run(f) { f.apply(null, Array().slice.call(arguments, 1)); }
run(show, 'foo', 'bar');
```