# how to create functions with variable arguments in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variadic-functions

I want to create a function in javascript with a variable amount of arguments. The next example is how I want to call this function:

```
myFunction(1,2);
myFunction(1,2,3);
myFunction(1,2,3,4);
myFunction(1,2,3,4,5);
myFunction(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Anyone knows how to define this function?

Comment: @TJHeuvel I don't agree, this is not the same question... Here tlaks about number of parameters and the other about default parameters

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can access the arguments by their ordinal position without the need to state them in the prototype as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    alert(arguments[i]);
}

myFunction(1, 2, "three");

>>1
>>2
>>three
```

Or if you really are passing in a set of semantically related numbers you could use an array;

```
function myFunction(arr) { ... }
result = myFunction([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: I also saw this solution in the book: "Javascript, the definitive guide". Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

#### Latest update

**Rest parameters** are supported in all new browsers.
[Check here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array, which you can pass it to other functions too.

```
function myFunction(...data){
  console.log(...data);
  myOtherFunction(...data);
}

myFunction(1,2,3);     //logs 1,2,3

myFunction([1,2,3]);   //logs [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'arguments' variable like this :

```
function myFunction() {
    alert(arguments.length + ' arguments');
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
    }
 }
```

Call the methods as you did before

```
myFunction(1,2);
myFunction(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just refer to the arguments array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 2):

If an argument is not present, use the default. Like this...

```
function accident() {
    //Mandatory Arguments
    var driver = arguments[0];
    var condition = arguments[1]

    //Optional Arguments
    var blame_on = (arguments[2]) ? arguments[2] : "Irresponsible tree" ;
}

accident("Me","Drunk");
```

Answer (score 1):

As an add-on: You can assign values to the unnamed function parameters, as in [(german wiki)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadische_Funktion#JavaScript)

```
arguments[0] = 5;
```