# Slice JS function's arguments

Tags: javascript

I want to write a common confirm method like

```
var confirmDelete = function (fun) {
    if (confirm("Do you want to delete " + arguments[1])) {
        $(arguments[2]).remove();
        fun(arguments[3]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's working fine for `fun` with one parameter, but I want to suit for two or more parameters, how I can do it?

Comment: Double check your syntax, something is not right, missing `)`

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass all parameters other than `fun` when you call `fun`?

Comment: yes, I want to call fun with arguments[3],arguments[4].....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every javascript Function object has a method named `apply`.  `apply` will call your function using the given context and the given arguments.

```
var confirmDelete=function(fun) {
    if(confirm("Do you want to delete "+ arguments[1])) {
        // remove the first two elements in arguments, and use the resulting array as a new set of
        // arguments to fun
        fun.apply(this, Array.slice(arguments, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Array.prototype.slice`?

Comment: Actually, `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2)`

Comment: @bfavaretto: Firefox supports Array generics :-) Other browsers dont!

Comment: @Bergi Didn't know that, just found [the docs and a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) on MDN. But I'm still fond of the "classic" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can pass as many parameters as you want.

If you don't pass them, they will be undefined.

So... You can do something like this:

```
var confirmDelete = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    if (typeof arg2 === 'undefined') {
        arg2 = "default value for arg2";
    }
    if (typeof arg3 === 'undefined') {
        arg3 = "default value for arg3";
    }
    // do more stuff...
}
```

---

You can also read about the magical `arguments` variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1959040/778118).

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function something like

```
var confirmDelete = function fun(arg1, arg2) {
  // number of parameter as your need
  // TODO some stuff
  fun(arg1 -1, arg2 +3); // call it recursively 
  return false; 
}
```