# Is there any way to pass multiple arguments to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, web-applications, arguments

Is there any way to pass the `arguments` to `jquery/javascript` like  below

```
function showContentDiv(args ......){
 //do some thing with looping args
}
```

and usage like

```
showContent("","","","");  //should change the parma count each time
```

Reason behind avoid preparing a array in jquery and passing is 
I have links like below

```
<a onclick="javaScript:showContent("val1","val2","val3")">

<a onclick="javaScript:showContent("val1","val2")">
```

Comment: Or maybe it's a duplicate of [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1959040/218196). I don't know if you are asking for how to create a variadic function or how to call one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript functions automatically have an [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) - an array-like object that includes elements for every parameter passed to the function.

The following example simply loops through any arguments and logs them to the console.

```
function showContentDiv(){
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
       console.log(arguments[i]);
   }
}
```

As an aside, don't include `javaScript:` at the beginning of your event attributes. This isn't required by any browser. `onclick="showContent()"` is fine. (Where by "fine" I mean "not as good as binding the events in a script block".)

Comment: It seems this is great,Lemme work on this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<a onclick="javaScript:showContent("val1,val2,val3")">

function showContentDiv(args){
var argsList=args.split(',');
for(i=0;i<argsList.length;i++)
{
argsList[i]
}
 //do some thing with looping args
}
```

Comment: What if you want to call `showContent()` with arguments that aren't all strings? For example, `showContent({'a':1,'b':[45,12,2]}, 'test', true)` - or a less contrived example, `showContent(func1, func2, func3)` (where the arguments are function references).