# how to send dynamic parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send parameters dynamically i.e.,(one time two parameters and another time 5 parameters like that). For Example 
Im having 4 arrays like., a1,a2,a3 and a4. if my condition is 2 then i need to send the any of the 2 arrays as a parameter(example : a1,a2 or a1,a3...). if my condition is 3 means i need to send 3 arrays as a parameter.

```
Example code:
var a1=[10,20,30,40];
var a2=[11,22,33,44];
var a3=[12,21,15,13];
var a4=[41,25,46,14];

Conditon : arrays==2 then

methodCall(a1,a3); or methodCall(a2,a3);
```

Please give me any suggestion for get the dynamic parameter.

Comment: `Function.prototype.apply` is what you need.

Comment: @putvande - That question isn't a duplicate, because it is specifically about how to have an array's elements become individual arguments in a function call. In this question the fact that the arguments are arrays is irrelevant. (Though that question does provide enough information to figure out an answer to this question.) It _is_ a duplicate of [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send a variable number of arguments in javascript. You have to use the `arguments` object inside the function to check the number of arguments and retrieve them. [This SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function) explains it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) inside the function to get the result

```
function sayHi() {
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    alert("Hi, " + arguments[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is `arguments` keyword available for this

```
function testme() {
    console.log(arguments.length);
}

testme(1,2,3); // 3
testme(1); //1
```