# What is the equivalent of Lua's ellipsis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, parameters, optional-parameters, ellipsis

In Lua, a function like this would be valid:

```lua
function FuncCallHack(Func, ...)
    return Func(...)
end
```

Is there a way I could do this in JavaScript? `...` means "all unindexed parameters in the form of an ungrouped array" to those unfamiliar with Lua. I have tried `...` in JavaScript, and it appeared to be nonfunctional, and as Google doesn't like searching for special characters, it's not much help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: Not a repeat question, read closer, and understand before commenting please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has the `arguments` pseudo-array and the `apply` function; you can do that like this:

```
function FuncCallHack(Func) {
    return Func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

here's how that works:

1. `arguments` - This is a pseudo-array containing all of the arguments passed to the function by the calling code (including the format argument `Func`).
2. `[].slice.call(arguments, 1)` is a way to get an array of all of the arguments except the first one. (It's a common idiom. It works by applying the `Array#slice` method to the `arguments` pseudo-array, using `Function#call` [which is a lot like `Function#apply` below, it just accepts the args to pass on differently].) Sadly, `arguments` itself doesn't necessarily have a `slice` method because it's not really an array.
3. Then we use the `Function#apply` method (all JavaScript functions have it) to call `Func` using the same `this` value that was used for the call to `FuncCallHack`, and passing on all of the arguments except `Func` to it.

You could also define it slightly differently:

```
function FuncCallHack(Func, args) {
    return Func.apply(this, args);
}
```

...which is still really easy to use:

```
FuncCallHack(SomeFunction, [1, 2, 3]);
// Note this is an array --^-------^
```

Comment: Note that `[].slice.call(arguments, 1)` must be used instead of `arguments.slice(1)` because `arguments` is not a real Array object.

Comment: Hacky, but works, ty :-) good thing the code I'm running is backend stuff, so hacky is permissible. it would be less hacky if you could get the number of named parameters, and slice to that number, instead of a hard coded number to slice by, but much appreciated.

Comment: A little confused, possibly a tail call issue, but your code evaluates to undefined args, but placing the slice in a variable, and passing it to the apply call works, I heard JS doesn't have tail calls, perhaps this is a case of that?

Comment: @JohnDoe: I've used this pattern hundreds of times, there's no reason the args should be undefined, I suspect that's something else (perhaps something async?). Example: http://jsbin.com/iXIxUpo/1 FWIW, I usually grab the `slice` function once and reuse it: http://jsbin.com/iXIxUpo/2 Re knowing how many formal parameters there are, you can get that from `FuncCallHack.length`: `return Func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, FuncCallHack.length);` - http://jsbin.com/iXIxUpo/3 Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Javascript does not yet support this feature.

Instead, you can loop through the `arguments` array-like object to see every parameter.

To get an array of all of the parameters after the first two (assuming two named parameters), you can write

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 comes native support for this, it's named [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
function FuncCallHack(Func, ...args) {
    return Func(...args)
}
```

[Feature availability](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rest-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

This may not work everywhere, but it's a neat trick to succinctly replicate `{...}` in JavaScript.

```js
function varg(f, a) {
    f = f || varg.caller || arguments.caller;
    a = a || f.arguments;
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(a, f.length);
}

function f(a) {
    var b;
    // varg() could be used in one of the following ways:
    b = varg();  // Non-standard: uses caller.
    b = varg(f); // Not strict compliant: uses a function's arguments property.
    b = varg(f, arguments); // Should be safe to use everywhere.
    return b;
}

console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(1, 2));
console.log(f(1, 2, 3));
```

---

What's going on here is that within `varg()`, the calling function is inferred from [`caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) and its arguments are determined by checking its [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) property. The argument pseudo-array is then sliced into a real array, starting from [`f.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), which represents the *arity*, or how many arguments is expected of the calling function, thus avoiding the need for any hard-coded magic numbers.

However, if the problem you're trying to solve is just redirecting a function's arguments into another's, then [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872132/828255) is more appropriate.

```
function FuncCallHack(Func) {
  return Func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```