# Control-Flow with NodeJS and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, bluebird

I have the following function:

```
 function retrieveNotifications(promotions) {
         promotions.forEach( function(promotion) {

             //find all notification groups that have to be notified
             db
               .Notification
                   .findAll()
                       .then(function (notifications) {
                           //some code that adds notifications to an object
                        });                       
         });         
  };
```

How can I restructure it to wait till all notifications are added to the object. I can't use `.then` because it would be called multiple times because of the `forEach`

Comment: You should be using `Promise.map` instead of that `forEach`, so that you can return a promise for your result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the async library: https://github.com/caolan/async

Basically it would go something like this:

```
async.parallel([ 
  // tasks..
], 
function () {
  // this is the final callback
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .spread() which is built into Sequelize/Bluebird:

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise

Have your forEach build up an array of `db.Notification.findAll()` and return it. Then call .spread on the result. If you don't know the length of the array returned you can use the `arguments` object in the success callback.

[Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

Now .spread() will wait until each element in the array has returned and pass you an array with all your Notification rows.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Bluebirds collection functions](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#collections), specifically `map`, `each` or `prop`. They will allow you to iterate your `promotions` array with an asynchronous callback, and you get a promise back that automatically resolves only when all of them have finished.

In your case it would look like this:

```
function retrieveNotifications(promotions) {
    return Promise.map(promotions, function(promotion) {
        // find all notification groups that have to be notified
        return db.Notification.findAll(… promotion …);
    }).then(function(results) {
        // results is an array of all the results, for each notification group
        var obj = {};
        for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            //some code that adds notifications to the object
        return obj;
    });
    // returns a promise for that object to which the notifications were added
}
```