# How to convert 'apply' to 'call' or the other

Tags: javascript

i need to replace method apply to call or the other.

```
this[aType].apply(this, aParams)
```

of course, aParams must be an array.

how can i do it?

i'm waiting your opinion

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in more detail. At this point, I have no idea what you mean by "convert", and I have no idea what you mean by "the other".

Comment: hey let me get u more clarified way-  You want to use call instead of the apply method. right?

Comment: What do you mean you "need" to? If `aParams` is an array then you *need* `.apply()` (unless you want the called function to accept the whole array as a single argument).

Comment: What is the point of using `Func#call` instead of `Func#apply` ?

Comment: I see that you've clarified that "convert" means "replace" . . . I still don't know what "the other" means.

Comment: `Function.apply.call(this[aType], this, aParams)` Now you have both :)

Comment: For Javascript varargs check: [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function). One way to differentiate the arguments would be to check on `argument` property inside the function...

Answer (score 2):

I cant really connect to why you exactly need it, as pointed by other users here. But in case you need it, I would say it`s an interesting problem to solve. And you might be definitely interested in the powers of [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operators in ES6 module.

Check how you can send an array of parameters using the call function here:

```js
function abc(x, y) {
  console.log(x, y);
}
var a = [1, 4];
abc.call(this, ...a)
```

Answer (score 1):

For .apply should use arguments as array,
But in .call using arguments as parameter.

```
var aParams = ['aParam1','aParam2'];

this[aType].apply(this, aParams);

this[aType].call(this,aParams[0],aParams[1]);
```

if its `n` number

```
for (var i = 0; i < aParams .length; i++) {
  (function(i) {

  }).call(this , aParams[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be an improvement for question but it does not answer the question..

Comment: Rayon, answer updated

Comment: I guess OP is quiet aware of how `apply/call` works.. What he is asking is _How to pass n number(dynamic) of arguments in `call`_

Comment: @Rayon I'm confused by what you just said. Isn't the way to pass `n` arguments to `call` simply to . . . pass `n` arguments to `call`?

Comment: @this-vidor– OP is asking what he does not know how many arguments are there ? Say I have an array of `n` length and I want to pass each item from array as argument..

Comment: Can we give for loop ,it n arguments  , like this,



for (var i = 0; i < aParams .length; i++) {
  (function(i) {

  }).call(this , aParams[i]);
}

Answer (score 0):

Pass the arguments to the call function

```
this[aType].call(this, aParams[0],aParams[1],aParams[2])
```

Comment: Change 'apply' to call