# Adding parameters to a function dynamically (non-restricted)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a way to pass multiple arrays as function parameters (dynamically), and store their values into a single array (I know how to do this part) as demonstrated bellow:

```
function arrayfunction (/*arrays go here*/) {
  var allArrays = []
}
arrayfunction([a,b,c],[d,e,f],[h,i,j],...);
```

how can that be done?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

Comment: a single array containing all the array values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should get you started

```
function arrayfunction (/*arrays go here*/) 
{
  var outputArr = [];
  for ( var counter = 0; counter < arguments.length; counter++)
  {
    outputArr = outputArr.concat( arguments[ counter ] );
  }
  return outputArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) if you are using babel or other transpiler which supports ES6.
For ES5 you can use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) keyword to get arguments passed to the function, but be ware that `arguments` is not an array, and you need to do something like `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);` to get an array.