# JQuery call function and multiple params from string

Tags: jquery

If I have a function:

```
function myfunc(param1, param2, param3) {
  // ...
}
```

and I have a string:

```
var myCall = "myfunc(1, 'abc', 'true')"
```

Is there a way to make the function call using the string and include the params?  I don't know the number of parameters in advance. 
I have tried

```
var func = myCall.substr(0, myCall.indexOf('('));
var args = myCall.substring(myCall.indexOf('(')+1, myCall.length-1);    
window[func](args.split(','));
```

but that just calls the function with an array to the first parameter.  How do I split the arguments and pass them in with an unknown number of parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function .This might Help its is like Vargs in Java

Comment: you can do `eval(myCall)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `Function` constructor:

```js
function myfunc(param1, param2, param3) {
    console.log(param1, param2, param3);
}

var myCall = "myfunc(1, 'abc', 'true')";
// here the 'myfunc' string indicates the name of a parameter that will
// be passed into the function that new Function is creating.
// i.e., we are going to pass in the myfunc function
// when we actually call myCaller
var myCaller = new Function('myfunc', myCall);

myCaller(myfunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace()` again with `RegExp` `/\(.*/` to replace all characters except for function name, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^\w+(?=\))|[()]/` to remove function name and parenthesis from string, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[\w\d]+/g` to match digit or word characters, `.map()` to return digit or word characters within an array, `Function.prototype.apply()` to pass array to function call

```
function myfunc(param1, param2, param3) {
  console.log(param1, param2, param3)
}

var myCall = "myfunc(1, 'abc', 'true')";

var fn = myCall.replace(/\(.*/, "");

var params = myCall.replace(/^\w+(?=\))|[()]/, "")
             .match(/[\w\d]+/g).map(function(param) {
               return /\d/.test(param) ? +param : param
             });

window[fn].apply(null, params);
```