# Using JavaScript, is it possible to create an array using a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm new to programming and for the moment I'm learning JavaScript using a combination of online courses. One challenge I'm working on is to use a function to return a random string from an array. That part itself was easy, but it seems like I need to be able to create the array from the input I give when I call the function. As an example, if I were to create a function like this:

`function namePicker(names);`

And I then called the function and gave it this input:

`namePicker("Billy","Timmy","Johnny");`

then I should be able to use the input to create an array of these names. However, when I tried to work this into the code for the random name picker, only the first name I gave would return to me.

What am I doing wrong here? Here's the full code I've been working on:

```
function lunchClubLottery(names) {
    var lunchClub = [names];    
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*lunchClub.length);
    return lunchClub[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

Comment: It did, but not on its own. I didn't understand what they were talking about until I read Ben's answer as well. Thank you for the link anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`...`) can be used to create an array of all (or some of) the arguments supplied to a function.

```js
function lunchClubLottery(...names) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)
    return names[i]
}

const name = lunchClubLottery("Billy","Timmy","Johnny")

console.log(name)
```

Or if you want to go old-school, you can use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) (if you are not using a fat arrow function).

Here I convert the array-like `arguments` object to an Array using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```js
function lunchClubLottery() {
    const names = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)
    return names[i]
}

const name = lunchClubLottery("Billy","Timmy","Johnny")

console.log(name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it really helped me out.